# Can "grub-emu" make any changes to my system?

Tags: command-line, grub2, emulation

Can "grub-emu" make any changes to my system? I understand that the command "grub-emu" opens a GRUB *emulator*. However, since it loads the configuration files used by the "real" GRUB, I am a little concerned that this emulator may be able to harm my system.

Is it completely safe to experiment with CLI-mode commands in grub-emu?

Comment: I always play around with things that remotely could cause my system to crash in a VM. As long as you don't start Firefox/OpenLibreOffice etc. you don't need much memory for that to work. You can reboot, while continue to work etc.

Answer (score -1):

you should copy your /boot files somewhere else and then run:

```
grub-emu --dir /the/copied/path
```